# Regroup two SELECT

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, bdd

This query select all from my first table where the row id doesnt exist in my second table:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT idTable1 FROM table2 WHERE table1.id=idTable1
```

This query select all row of `table1` who exists in the `table2` with the last id of `table2` ( cause one row of `table1` can have multiple row of the `table2` but only the last is not forget ):

```
SELECT *
FROM table2
    INNER JOIN table 1 ON idTable1 = table1.id
WHERE table2.id IN (SELECT MAX(actioncur.id) FROM table2 GROUP BY idTable1)
```

I want to regroup the both query in one, I want to select all row of `table1` when id doesnt exist in `table2` and select all of the `table1` for the last `table2` id.                                   For exemple i want to select that : row 1 -> id=44 ; table2.id= 187 ; idTable1=44. Row 2 ->id=45 ; table2.id=? ; idTable1=?

Comment: show dummy data and expected output

Comment: read about SQL UNION...https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp

Comment: Roy i cant use the UNION cause the both query dont have the sam number of column

Comment: For exemple i want to select that :                                row 1 -> id=44 ; table2.id= 187 ; idTable1=44.                         Row 2 ->id=45 ; table2.id=? ; idTable1=?

Comment: I suggest you to write that example into post, just edit it

Comment: Ok i'll edit it

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT t1.*,
       (SELECT MAX(t2.id)
        FROM table2 t2
        WHERE t1.id = t2.idTable1
       ) as max_t2id
FROM table1 t1;
```

You can also do this with `LEFT JOIN` and `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT t1.*, MAX(t2.id) as max_t2id
FROM table1 t1 JOIN
     table2 t2
     ON t1.id = t2.idTable1
GROUP BY t1.id;
```